# How to run selected junit tests with different parameters

Tags: java, junit, customization, parameterized

I want to run selected test methods from any test class with different parameters

Ex: 1) ClassA -> Test methods A, B

```
@Test
public void testA(String param) {
    System.out.println("From A: "+param);
}
@Test
public void testB(String param) {
}
```

2) ClassB -> Test methods C, D

```
@Test
public void testC(String param) {
    System.out.println("From C: "+param);
}
@Test
public void testD(String param) {
}
```

From these I want to run following tests 
1) testA(from ClassA) two times with diff params "test1" & "test2" 
2) testC(from ClassB) two times with diff params "test3" & "test3"

Here my test count should show as '4'

Can anyone help on this...

Comment: How are you running your tests. Are you using the IDE or a build tool like Maven?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try using JUnit parameterized testing. Here is a [tutorial from TutorialsPoint.com](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/junit/junit_parameterized_test.htm):

> JUnit 4 has introduced a new feature called **parameterized tests**. Parameterized tests allow a developer to run the same test over and over again using different values. There are five steps that you need to follow to create a parameterized test.
>
> - Annotate test class with @RunWith(Parameterized.class).
> - Create a public static method annotated with @Parameters that returns a Collection of Objects (as Array) as test data set.
> - Create a public constructor that takes in what is equivalent to one "row" of test data.
> - Create an instance variable for each "column" of test data.
> - Create your test case(s) using the instance variables as the source of the test data.
>
> The test case will be invoked once for each row of data.

Answer (score 20):

Use Parameterized tests provided with Junits, wherein you can pass the parameters at run time.

Refer to [org.junit.runners.Parameterized](http://junit.org/junit4/javadoc/4.12/org/junit/runners/Parameterized.html) (JUnit 4.12 offers the possibility to parametrize with expected values and without expected values in the setup array).

Try this:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TestA {

   @Parameterized.Parameters(name = "{index}: methodA({1})")
   public static Iterable<Object[]> data() {
      return Arrays.asList(new Object[][]{
            {"From A test1", "test1"}, {"From A test2", "test2"}
      });
   }

   private String actual;
   private String expected;

   public TestA(String expected,String actual) {
      this.expected = expected;
      this.actual = actual;
   }

   @Test
   public void test() {
      String actual = methodFromA(this.actual);
      assertEquals(expected,actual);
   }

   private String methodFromA(String input) {
      return "From A " + input;
   }
}
```

you can write a similar test for class B.

For a test taking just single parameters, fro JUnit 4.12 you can do this:

```
@RunWith(Parameterized.class)
public class TestU {

    /**
     * Provide Iterable to list single parameters
     */

    @Parameters
    public static Iterable<? extends Object> data() {
        return Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
    }

    /**
     * This value is initialized with values from data() array
     */

    @Parameter
    public String x;

    /**
     * Run parametrized test
     */

    @Test
    public void testMe() {
        System.out.println(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also correct answer. Need to write code for dynamic parameters in parameterized method and assign to the array.